# Redirect to another page on click of button

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I had made a button through which I want to redirect to another page using angularjs.

It can be done if I write the code on the same page on which the button is created but i don't want to do that. So help me.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm bg-darkgreen addemployeeformbtn"<a href="#/SampleManagementView/>><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; Add New</a></button>  </li>
```

Comment: *It can be done if I write the code on the same page on which the button is created but i don't want to do that.* -- so what *do* you want to do?

Comment: Try changing `href="#/SampleManagementView/` to `href="/SampleManagementView/`

Comment: I had made another page on which i want to redirect on button click

Comment: Do you have routing?

Comment: Try angular routing to keep it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" ng-click="redirect()" ...>
```

And on controller:

```
$scope.redirect = function(){
    $window.location = "../#/SampleManagementView/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <nav>
      <a routerLink="/SampleManagementView">Sample Management</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Make sure you have given correct name and routing path. In detail refer this link -: https://angular.io/start/routing